# An efficent way to draw this graph on overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

[image]

I can't find an efficent way to draw this graph on overleaf. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to draw this graph?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not a fluent TikZ user.  If I'm faced with such a problem, I scan the documentation for a similar example.